# Baofeng not finding CTCSS tone

Tags: ht, baofeng, tone-squelch

I have this Baofeng and I want listen to my school radios. The problem is that I want to find the CTCSS tone for the fun of it, but when I scan the tones on the Baofeng it cycles through but does not stop on one. I know that the school uses a little 35 Watt repeater but the input frequency does not yield any tone when I scan it. Do you think the school uses a non-standard CSCSS tone? Also, could they be using a DCS tone? Thanks!

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it is not asking for _guesses_ about what the repeater is doing. Questions should have answers that can be seen to be accurate just from reading the question and answer — not by visiting your school.

Comment: Well why don't you try scanning with DCS as well and see what happens? Also are you sure that they're using a continuous tone squelch? I spend quite a bit of time trying to figure out the tone of a local repeater that used a 1750 Hz tone burst to disable squelch.

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct frequency for the scan? "School radios", unless there is an official amateur radio station, can not use amateur radio frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

They may not be transmitting a tone at all.  I had this with my Baofeng and a local club repeater I wanted to access.  They only receive the tone but do not transmit it because then others would know what it is and could use it without paying dues to the club.  The school may be of the same mind.

Answer (score 0):

It could be no tone, it could be DCS, or it could have an activation tone. It could even be a very, very simple trunking system implemented in an odd way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine the repeater input frequency? If so, you could try running the tone scan on the input frequency, this would help in the case that the tone is not output by the repeater.